# VSCode Ignoring breakpoints

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Im trying to debug my python project and its ignoring breakpoints, just executes the entire program:

[image]

Comment: Please indicate what you've already tried.  Did you follow the instructions for debugging python apps?  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_configure-and-run-the-debugger

Answer (score 0):

Those look kindof like ***disabled*** breakpoints. But they are hollow?

Disabled/enabled breakpoints look like this,you can right-click them to dis-/enable:

[image: breakpoints in VS]

Comment: my breakpoints are red, when i run them, still like this!